# RStudio equivalent to pressing tab twice in terminal

Tags: r, terminal, rstudio

In Terminal on OS X, typing the start of a function name and hitting tab twice brings up all R functions that begin with that name.

For example, type `mean` then hit tab twice and the output is:

```
mean           mean.POSIXct   mean.default   
mean.Date      mean.POSIXlt   mean.difftime
```

Is there an equivalent to this in RStudio?

Comment: I dont like using RStudio much, but the closest I am aware of to the functionality of terminal is to hit tab once, and then scroll up and down the list.

Comment: Is there a way to actually list the functions in the console in RStudio, after having pressed tab once?

Comment: It does get listed, but just not in the way one is used to from Terminal.  So really, no.

Comment: you might want to post this question in the RStudio forum as I believe their engineering team is active there and might be able to give you a more knowledgable answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that with RStudio right now.  You could use a kludgy workaround though by defining a binary operator that sort of does what you want

```
`%T%` <- function(x, y){
  x <- as.character(substitute(x))
  apropos(paste0("^", x))
}
```

The second input can be (almost) anything but doesn't get used so it doesn't matter too much.  I opt to use a period because it's easy

```
mean %T%.

> # Example use with period
> mean %T%.
[1] "mean"          "mean.Date"     "mean.default"  "mean.difftime"
[5] "mean.POSIXct"  "mean.POSIXlt" 
> # works with other stuff too..
> lm %T%.
[1] "lm"           "lm.fit"       "lm.influence" "lm.wfit"     
> # Feel free to use whatever you want for the second input
> # except just a space or %
> lm%T%aasdf
[1] "lm"           "lm.fit"       "lm.influence" "lm.wfit"
```

This method isn't perfect.  For instance

```
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot %T%.
[1] "ggplot"        "ggplot_build"  "ggplot_gtable" "ggplotGrob"
```

but if I use the double tab method then 'ggplot2::' also shows up in the output list.

Using this method "tab-tab" becomes "space-%-T-%-." which isn't nearly as nice but I really don't think there is a way to do what you want in RStudio currently.  But that's alright with me because I kind of like the way they're doing it because you get the additional info about the function argument list and the general description.

Comment: This also isn't case sensitive and gets thrown off in certain situations.  For example `+. %T%.` doesn't give the same output as the double tab method...